# Windows object file/static library compiler compatability

Tags: c, windows, static-libraries

I have produced a static library (`.lib`) file using the `mingw` win32 cross-build toolchain on linux.

A colleague wishing to link their application to this library have failed with many `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol` type errors. They were using MSVS2008. They tried using my `.lib` file and also creating their own static lib using `lib.exe` and the set of object (`.o`) files that I produced. Both approaches produced the same errors.

I successfully linked to the `.lib` file to make an executable that ran on windows10 with no issue. Obviously using the same compiler though, i.e. `mingw` rather that `MSVS2008`.

Is it incorrect to assume that you can link an application to a static library using disparate compilers?

We haven't had any problems linking using shared libraries (`.dlls`) across compilers.

Comment: Yep, no chance of this working. For static libraries you'll need the consumer to be using the same toolchain as you.

Comment: but this issue goes away when you use .dlls right?

Comment: it does beg the question why are .lib files distributed in software packages? You're only able to utilise them if you happen to have an identical toolchain?

Comment: I guess you'd have to ask whoever is doing that why they chose to do so

Comment: Possibly I'm getting confused with linux packages distributing .a files? I'm sure I've seen static libs alongside .so and .dll files though when downloading software packages? Or am I having some sort of bad dream?